# Price calculator for Constrained vCPU capable VM sizes

Tags: azure, iaas

I am trying to estimate the Total cost(including SQL Server License) of [Constrained vCPU capable VM sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/constrained-vcpu) using [Price calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/), but it is not available in the drop down list.

Eg VM Sizes - Standard_E16-8s_v3, and Standard_DS14-8_v2

How can I get this?

Cheers

Comment: It looks like they now appear but don't provide the correct price estimation. eg DS13 and DS13-4 show the same price with SQL when my understanding is it should be cheaper for only 4 cores of SQL licence.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to find out a cost estimate for a specific combination of SQL Server edition and virtual machine size, see the [pricing page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-server-pricing-guidance). Select your operating system and SQL Server edition from the OS/Software list. Refer: [Pricing guidance for SQL Server Azure VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-server-pricing-guidance)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I cannot find VM's like Standard_DS14-8_v2, Standard_E16-8s_v3, etc.